# How to create two Instances of the Simple Ajax Uploader Dropzone in One Project but in different modals

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Two things not working:

1. During Upload Progress Bar is not Working
2. Implementation of this code in two different Bootstrap Modals but working separately and Independently in both modals.

I tried to change the ID `progressContainer` in HTML part of a Modal Body to `progressContainer2` and `var` `uploader` in JavaScript to `uploader2` thought may be it will work but by doing so uploaded file or `ProgressContainer` shows in just one Modal and other stops working.

How to make it work separately independent in both modals?

```js
var uploader;

function createUploader(i, elem) {

  var elem = $(elem);
  var type = elem.data("type");
  var dropzone = elem.find('.uploadDropzone');
  var btn = elem.find('.btnUpload');
  var progBox = elem.find('.uploadProgress');
  var msgBox = elem.find('.uploadMessage');
  var maxsize = 20000;

  function showUploadMessage(msg, result) {
    msgBox.text(msg).addClass(result).show();
  }

  function hideUploadMessage() {
    msgBox.text('').removeClass('error').removeClass('unknown').removeClass('success').hide();
  }

  //create uploader(s)

  uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
    button: btn,
    dropzone: dropzone,
    /*url: 'your_php_file.php',*/
    name: 'uploadfile',
    progressBar: progBox,
    multipart: true,
    disabledClass: 'disabled',
    responseType: 'json',
    allowedExtensions: ["pdf"],
    maxSize: maxsize,
    multiple: true,
    multipleSelect: true,
    maxUploads: 10,
    queue: false,
    startXHR: function() {},
    onSubmit: function(filename) {

      hideUploadMessage(); //hide any previous errors

      const progressBox = document.getElementById('progressContainer');

      const wrapper = document.createElement('div')
      wrapper.className = 'row ps-0 wrapper';

      const fileNamef = document.createElement('div');
      fileNamef.className = 'col-6 pe-0 name';
      fileNamef.innerHTML = '<span>' + filename + '</span>';

      const fileSize = document.createElement('div');
      fileSize.className = 'col-2 d-flex justify-content-center size';

      const progress = document.createElement('div');
      progress.className = 'col-3 progress me-0 mt-2';
      const bar = document.createElement('div');
      bar.className = 'progress-bar';

      const close = document.createElement('button');
      close.className = ' col-1 d-flex justify-content-end deleteAttachment';

      // Assemble the progress bar and add it to the page

      wrapper.appendChild(fileNamef);
      wrapper.appendChild(fileSize);
      progress.appendChild(bar);
      wrapper.appendChild(progress);
      wrapper.appendChild(close);

      progressBox.appendChild(wrapper);

      $(wrapper).data('file', filename);


      this.setProgressBar(bar);
      this.setFileSizeBox(fileSize);
      this.setAbortBtn(close);
      //this.setProgressContainer(wrapper); // designate the containing div to be removed after upload
    },

    onSizeError: function() {
      var msg = 'Files may not exceed ' + maxsize + 'k.';
      showUploadMessage(msg, 'error');
    },

    onExtError: function() {
      var msg = 'Please select only PDF file';
    },

    onComplete: function(filename, response) {

      $('.wrapper').filterByData('file', filename).addClass('success'); //add a 'completed' class to the wrapper when file succeeds.

      if (!response) {
        var msg = 'Unable to upload file(s).';
        showUploadMessage(msg, 'error');
        return;
      }

      if (response.success === true) {

        //things to do after complete, such as show image;
        $(file.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>');
      } else {

        if (response.msg) {
          var msg = escapeTags(response.msg);
          showUploadMessage(msg, 'error');
        } else {
          var msg = 'Sorry! Unable to upload one of your files.';
          showUploadMessage(msg, 'error');
        }
      }
    },
    onError: function() {

      var msg = 'Unable to upload file(s) to server.  Please try again later.';
      showUploadMessage(msg, 'error');
      $('.wrapper').removeClass('success').addClass('error');

    }

  });
}

$('.uploadContainer').each(createUploader);

$(document).on('click', '.deleteAttachment', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var wrapper = $(this).closest('.wrapper');
  wrapper.remove();

  // ... Back-end-dev should add a function to actually delete the image from the server.

});
```

```css
.uploadContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.uploadDropzone {
  content: "";
  border: 2px dashed #DADBDF;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.uploadDropzone .cloud {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: .5;
}

.uploadMessage {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

.uploadProgress {
  margin-top: .5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: thin solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.uploadProgress:empty {
  background: none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
}

.wrapper {
  width: auto;
}

.uploadProgress .wrapper {
  position: static;
  background-color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: thin solid #d2d2d2;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.uploadProgress .wrapper:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.uploadProgress .wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.uploadProgress .name {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.uploadProgress .size {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #aaa;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.uploadProgress .size:before {
  content: "(";
}

.uploadProgress .size:after {
  content: ")";
}

.uploadProgress .progress {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.uploadProgress .deleteAttachment {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  background-image: none;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.deleteAttachment:after {
  content: '\00D7';
  display: block;
  line-height: inherit;
  width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.uploadProgress .wrapper.success {
  color: green;
}

.uploadProgress .wrapper.error {
  color: red;
}

.uploadProgress .error .progress {
  color: gold;
}

.uploadProgress .success .progress {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/6.0.0-beta.2/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/6.0.0-beta.2/dropzone.js"></script>
<script src="https://btn.ninja/js/SimpleAjaxUploader.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-12 mt-3">
  <div class="uploadContainer">
    <button type="button" class="col-12 btn bg-transparent border-0 link btnUpload">
      <div class="dotdash uploadDropzone">
        <h5>Drag & Drop</h5>
        <p>Your File Here or Browse to Upload</p>
        <small class="text-prime">Only PDF Files with max size of 20 MB</small>
      </div>
    </button>
    <div class="alert uploadMessage" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="progressContainer" class="col-12 uploadProgress"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```